selenium.webdriver.Firefox with FirefoxOptions().add_argument('--headless') doesn't return a valid hwnd
I've noticed that the headless option in Firefox runs Firefox in the background without a window attached to it, and I haven't been able to find a way to run Firefox in the background and still have the hwnd of the Firefox window to be able to use.
I started out using pyvda to get an AppView of Firefox, but pyvda.get_apps_by_z_order didn't return anything so I wrote this and I was able to find two hwnds but nether one of them have a visible window. I was able to get one of them to show up on my taskbar without the conditional if statement.
Update...
Using what is being shown in the Task Manager I was able to figure out that these two hwnds being show in the code blow are child processes of Firefox with the same pid.
from inspect import currentframe
from typing import Optional

from psutil import Process
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
from win32con import SW_SHOW
from win32gui import EnumWindows, GetWindowText, ShowWindow, IsWindowVisible
from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId as GetPID


def main():
    def get_child_pid(process: Optional[Process] = None) -> Process | int:
        nonlocal firefox

        if process is None:
            process = Process(pid = firefox.service.process.pid)

        for child in process.children():
            if child.name() == 'firefox.exe':
                if len(child.children()):
                    process = get_child_pid(process = child)
                else:
                    break

        if currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name == 'main':
            return process.pid

        return process

    def enum_windows(hwnd: int, pid: int):
        if GetPID(hwnd)[1] == pid and len(GetWindowText(hwnd)):
            print(GetWindowText(hwnd), (visible := bool(IsWindowVisible(hwnd))), sep = ': ')
            if visible:
                ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW)

    options = FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    firefox = Firefox(options = options)

    EnumWindows(enum_windows, get_child_pid())

    # firefox.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


I need to find a way to be able to load Firefox in the background with a valid window that I can get the hwnd from.

why would you expect them to be visible?  btw, the driver has driver.window_handles method which returns an array of window/tab handles.  Process handles are probably a little different though and won't necessarily have a display or window at all, even if you weren't running headless... (modern browsers will separate domains to different processes)

@browsermator With what is being used in the code above I don't expect any of them to even have a window attached to it. I'm trying to find a way to run Firefox in the background with a window attached to it, but from what I've explored so far I'm thinking that I won't be able to achieve this. With ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE) I've been able to hide windows on my desktop.

you could try just launching Geckodriver in normal mode and then minimizing.  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#minimize-window
